# How to update the text shown on a status strip's label

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I created a status strip on my main form and a label within it. And I am opening another form within this (MdiContainer is true). For opening I am passing the object of main form in the constructor i.e. this. There I am updating the text of the label but its not getting updated.
I tried invalidate function also.

Comment: your answer is hidden in your 14 unaccepted questions :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was having this problem too. The fix is to add a line of code that fires events (see the second line below)

```
MainForm.mainStatusLabel.Text = "Importing data file" //see next line
Application.DoEvents()
```

I don't completely understand why this works, but my guess is that VB does not handle Application-wide events in the middle of a method unless you tell it to. When you change the text property, this is an event. So VB will (Im guessing) wait until the end of the method before handling the event--unless you tell it specifically to handle all events with Application.DoEvents()

Comment: Less of a hack is to call `Update()` which updates all controls on the Form.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of passing the instance of the MainForm to the ChildForm, define a custom event in the ChildForm, raise the event with the message that you want to show (as argument), then subscribe the event in MainForm, and in the eventhandler update the control text with the message. You may also have to check Control.InvokeRequired.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the problem, in my case because the text was too long to be displayed (Contained an exception message.) I set the SizingGrip property to 'False', so my text was shown (but trunkated).